# No spec found in Protractor with cucumber and typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am working on Protractor with Cucumber and Typescript
I am trying to run simple login test but I am getting No spec found
Here is my config file

```
import { browser, Config } from "protractor";
const path = require('path')
var downloadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../downloads');
exports.config = { 
directConnect:true,
frameworl:'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
baseUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/',

specs: ['./Feature/login.feature'],

capabilities: {
  browserName: "chrome",
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['allow-file-access-from-files'],
    prefs: {
      download: {
        'prompt_for_download': false,
        'directory_upgrade': true,
        'default_directory': downloadsPath
      },
    }
}
},

cucumberOpts:{
    require:["./StepDefinitions/LoginSteps.js"],
    compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    format: "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
    tags: ["@Smoke"],
    strict: true,
    
}, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved the problem was with the path specs: ['./Feature/login.feature'],
The correct path was specs: ['../Feature/login.feature'],
Please check the path of the files if you face similar issue